# Regex to remove newline; works in one vim instance, but not another

Tags: regular-expression

Trying to remove newlines with a regular expression (not shift-j).
I have one vim install where

```
:g/conf/s/\n//
```

works as intended, removing a newline from all lines containing 'conf'.
I have a second install where the same command has no obvious effect at all, other than highlighting the last character in the line.
Is there something that I can look for in the configurations to find out why one install is working as expected and one isn't?
Both installs are Linux, vim 7.4, 2013-08-10 build.

Comment: Is it possible the `ignorecase` setting differs between the two? (`:se ic?`)

Comment: Do they both use the same `.vimrc` and `$HOME`? You can get those values with `:echo $MYVIMRC` and `:echo $HOME`.

Comment: 'noignorecase' is set in both cases.  They don't use the same configuration files. Different users, different machines. I can echo out the contents of .vimrc and also look at :set all, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. .vimrc is pretty bare-bones in both.

Comment: Editing the same file? Sure of the fileformat (unix v. dos endings)?